# Returning a value that is not really a model using ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data.

I have a search screen that lazy loads data using `ember.infinitescroll`. I need to display the total number of records returned (which I can only find out by doing a server call as I don't have all records loaded locally)

The result will be something like this (the format can change as necessary)

```
{
  "totalRecords" : 552
}
```

This is not really a model, what is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Just a regular old ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `meta` in your API response. Ember data is aware of this

HTTP API Response

```
{
  posts: [ ... ]
  meta: {
    page: 5,
    totalPages: 70,
    totalRecords: 700
  }
}
```

Ember code would be:

```
result = this.store.find('post', { page: 5 });
totalRecords = result.get("content.meta.totalRecords");
```

See more here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/